# Golang:which way is more efficient about using "for range"

Tags: go

```
type path []byte

func (p path) ToUpper() {
    for i, b := range p {
        if 'a' <= b && b <= 'z' {
            p[i] = b + 'A' - 'a'
        }
    }
}
```

in the above(this example is copy from "The Go Blog"), if ToUpper change like this:

```
func (p path) ToUpper() {
    for i, _ := range p {
        if 'a' <= p[i] && p[i] <= 'z' {
            p[i] = p[i] + 'A' - 'a'
        }
    }
}
```

which will be more efficient

WHY?

"The Go Blog" says with the former one:
"Here the ToUpper method uses two variables in the for range construct to capture the index and slice element. This form of loop avoids writing p[i] multiple times in the body."

what is mean?

Answer (score 0):

The former has more memory operations, namely on `b`: it is allocated in the first run of the loop and reassigned in each subsequent run in addition to `i` *and* the original slice is modified, whereas in the second example, only `i` is allocated and reassigned and used to make modifications to the original slice.

Comment: But the former also has fewer bounds checks, and b might never leave a register.  You can't make any assumptions without benchmarking and / or inspecting the generated assembly.

Comment: @JimB: Thanks for the input – again, the meaning of a split "assume" comes true. Since you were friendly enough not to down vote me, I'd do it myself as an act of repentance, if it was possible.

Comment: FYI, the former is measurably faster on my machine with go1.6